# Extracting Browser Element from User Agent

Tags: php, mysql, browser, user-agent

I'm still working on the whole gathering user data from a visit thing, so I'm hung up on grabbing the actual name of the browser being used by the visitor. I have this code, but it seems that after execution, `$browser` is empty.

```
  $userAgent = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
  $browser = get_browser($userAgent, true);
  print_r($browser);
```

What am I doing wrong here, and what steps do I take next to extract the browser from the array?

*EDIT*

Okay so now I have the following code:

```
  $browser = get_browser(null, true);
  $userAgent = $browser["browser"];
  $browser = mysql_real_escape_string($userAgent);
  echo $browser;
```

Which does nothing. Any insight?

Comment: Why are you preparing the user agent string for inserting into a MySQL query when you aren't making an SQL query of any kind?

Comment: Well, I am. I just didn't include that part because that's one of the parts that is working.

Comment: Why are you passing the string that is prepared for MySQL to the function designed to operate on the raw User Agent string?

Comment: I'd guess that the escaping done by mysql_real_escape_string() is interfering with the parsing done by get_browser().  Try applying escaping *after* you have parsed the user-agent string, or else use the solution by @Ventus.

Comment: I hope you have browscap.ini set up correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to php.net when first parameter of `get_browser` is set to `null` then default "the value of HTTP User-Agent header is used". So look at this code.

```
$browser = get_browser(null,true);
$userAgent = $browser["browser_name_pattern"];
```